# Most efficient way to save JSON data and reuse on next page in JQuery

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, cordova

On my **(Cordova, jQuery-Mobile) iOS mobile application** I receive some **JSON** values on the first page.
To store them I use arrays.

To pass them and reuse them on the second page I use a **each function**, count up an **integer(i)** on every run and push the received data into **several arrays**, the integer(i) I store in a **DIV** in **data-id**. (`<div data-id'"+i+"'>`)

As soon as the User navigates to the second page by tapping on one of the DIVs I use the integer(i) in data-id to get every value from the arrays and display on page 2.

Example

**Database:**

```
ID NAME SURNAME AGE USERID
1 Michael Douglas 44 uid3242
2 Eric Cartman 11 uid9275
3 Felix Woodspuck 38 uid3852
4 Amadeus Mozart 158 uid1120
```

**Script:**

```
ID = [];
NAME = [];
SURNAME = [];
AGE = [];
USERID = [];
```

for example - If the user clicks on the DIV with data-id=2

```
iInt = $(this).attr('data-id'); // iInt=2
$("#abc").text(NAME[iInt];) // NAME[2]; --> Eric
$("#xyz").text(SURNAME[iInt];) // SURNAME[2]; --> Cartman
...
```

This is just an example, please ignore the values.

But in my App I am using a lot of variables on a lot of pages, and it gets a little messy in code, **so what I am wondering about is if there is a more efficent way to save the values I get from JSON to use them on the second page?** How do you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've been tucking the JSON string into localstorage, then pulling it out later and restoring to an object.

```
localStorage.setItem("jsondata",mytextvar);
```

Then later:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jsondata"));
```